# Django Models: getting data using a filter, empty

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to list all data on a page from table 'points_points' where user_id is the user logged in. However, the object is blank when displayed no data is listed. I 100% have data in the DB for  the user. Why does nothing display? Can anyone spot any mistakes below?

**models.py**

```
class PointsManager(models.Manager):

    def points_list(self,thisUser):
        list = Points.objects.filter(user=thisUser)
        return list


class Points (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("Points"), default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(("Created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=("Updated at"), auto_now=True)

    objects = PointsManager()


    class Meta:
      verbose_name = ('Point')
      verbose_name_plural = ('Points')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def history(request):

    thisPoints = Points.objects.points_list(request.user)
    context = {'points':thisPoints}
    return render_to_response('points/history.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template.py**

```
    <h1>|{{ points }}|</h1>

 {% for item in points.Points_items.all %}

     <tr>
       <td>{{ item.points }}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def points_list(self,thisUser):
       return super(PointsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user=thisUser)
```

Your template doesn't looks right..

```
{% for item in points %}

     <tr>
       <td>{{ item.points }}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```